# JQuery AJAX - Referenced variable gets overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
myVar=0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    $.ajax({
        //AJAX Paramters
    }).success((response) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem(myVar+'Stored', JSON.stringify(response['somekey']))
    });
    myVar++;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve: Storing the keys [myVar0Stored, myVar1Stored, ...] into the session storage.

Problem: If the AJAX call takes a long time, myVar=3 could happen before the previous keys are stored, meaning there won't be "myVar0Stored, myVar1Stored, myVar2Stored" keys. If I were to make synchronous GET requests, it could lock the browser until the response is received. I'm not sure how to approach this if I want to store the keys in the session storage.

tl;dr - How do I get the value of myVar before it gets updated in the loop?

Comment: Use closure. `(function (index) {
  $.ajax({
   //AJAX Paramters
  }).success((response) => {
   sessionStorage.setItem(index + 'Stored', JSON.stringify(response['somekey']))
  });
 })(myVar);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are making `myVar` a global in the first place. The root of the problem is that, as the `myVar` inside the arrow function will be the current value of the global variable. If you just use `let i` (which is also going from 0 to 4 anyway) it will have a local scope which will ensure that the `i` referenced in the arrow function will be specific to that iteration of the loop...

```
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
   $.ajax({
      //AJAX Paramters
   }).success((response) => {
      sessionStorage.setItem(i+'Stored', JSON.stringify(response['somekey']))
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem faced in asynchronous execution same problem you will get if u use timeout also, to solve this use function inside that function to make ajax call.

Problem lies here when you are trying to execute and use the value of myVar, ti will be changed 
So to solve this u must not use same myVar variable rather than call a function pass myVar as parameter in that function make ajax call so that what ever value you have passed will be used rather than a variable

```
myVar = 0
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
(function(myVar) {
    $.ajax({
    //AJAX Paramters
}).success((response) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(myVar+'Stored', JSON.stringify(response['somekey']))
});
})(i);
myVar++
}
```

You can write othe way also like this

```
myVar=0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
makeAjaxCall(myVar)

myVar++;
}


function makeAjaxCall(i) {
 $.ajax({
    //AJAX Paramters
}).success((response) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(myVar+'Stored', JSON.stringify(response['somekey']))
});
}
```